# MPLAB X IDE Redefinition Error after MPLAB 8 Import Project

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, mplab-x

Redefinition error due to typdef enum and pic header file. Defining AN1 to AN12 in two different header files - wont build

HI All,

I have a MPLAB 8 project which I have imported over to MPLAB X IDE. I've managed to change some of the C Standard settings to get it down to just one repeated error now which is:

> ../source/kADC.h:31:5: error: redefinition of 'AN1'
> C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC18Fxxxx_DFP/1.2.26/xc8\pic\include\proc\pic18f2321.h:6105:41: note: previous definition is here
> extern volatile __bit                   AN1                 __at(0x7C01);       // @ (0xF80 * 8 + 1)

I think it is due to a typedef enum redefining the AN's as well as them being defined in the PICS header file.

in kADC.h

```c
typedef enum ADC_CHANNEL_ENUM
{
    AN0 = 1,
    AN1,
    AN2,
    AN3,
    AN4,
    AN8,
    AN9,
    AN10,
    AN11,
    AN12,
    NO_READING
} ADCChannelEnum;
```

in pic18f2321.h

```c
extern volatile __bit                   AN0                 __at(0x7C00);   // @ (0xF80 * 8 + 0)
#define                                 AN0_bit             BANKMASK(PORTA), 0
// PORTA<AN1>
extern volatile __bit                   AN1                 __at(0x7C01);   // @ (0xF80 * 8 + 1)
#define                                 AN1_bit             BANKMASK(PORTA), 1
// PORTB<AN10>
extern volatile __bit                   AN10                __at(0x7C09);   // @ (0xF81 * 8 + 1)
#define                                 AN10_bit            BANKMASK(PORTB), 1
// PORTB<AN11>
extern volatile __bit                   AN11                __at(0x7C0C);   // @ (0xF81 * 8 + 4)
#define                                 AN11_bit            BANKMASK(PORTB), 4
// PORTB<AN12>
extern volatile __bit                   AN12                __at(0x7C08);   // @ (0xF81 * 8 + 0)
#define                                 AN12_bit            BANKMASK(PORTB), 0
// PORTA<AN2>
extern volatile __bit                   AN2                 __at(0x7C02);   // @ (0xF80 * 8 + 2)
#define                                 AN2_bit             BANKMASK(PORTA), 2
```

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Show us the file in which you include those two headers

Comment: You should only include `xc.h` and not `pic18f4321.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use `ADC_CHANNEL_ENUM` outside of your *kADC.c* file, move your enum definition into your *kADC.c* file so that the enum definition becomes private. This way you can prevent the redefinition errors.

But if you have to use `ADC_CHANNEL_ENUM` outside of your *kADC.c* file, then you'll have to change the names i.e.; instead of `AN0` use `ANLG0`.

Another way to prevent this, is not a preferrable way which implies to not include *xc* or *pic18f2321* headers. This makes all the convenient hardware specific definitions unavailable to your project, resulting to be more inconvenient for you.

As far as I see, you haven't used any `ADC_CHANNEL_ENUM` in the main file, but I don't know whether you have more files in your project and use that enum in them (you can specify if any so). Then you can consider the making the enum definition private to *kADC.c* file.

Go ahead and try one of the options above to see which would best fit for your case.

Comment: Perfect changing AN0 to a different name works great thank you